# My flash drive bent and the board is broken. Can I recover my data?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My Sandisk iXpand Flash Drive 16 GB 3.0 was connected my laptop when it was placed down and bent. The back popped off and the connectors are still intact from what I can tell, but the board seems to be broken? Am I able to recover my data?

Answer (score 2):

That depends.

If any of the memory ICs are physically broken, then no, you can't recover your data.

But if the memory ICs are intact, then it *might* be possible to either repair the board, or transplant the memory ICs to another USB flash memroy module of the same make and model. You'd need to find an electronics technician with micro-surface-mount de-soldering and soldering equipment and skills. How much such a person would charge you, is between you and him/her.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you *can* recover your data.  The question is how much effort and/or cost will it incur.  Your post lacks description, so I am assuming the drive is no longer functioning.

I am also assuming you lack electronics skills, such as soldering and testing.  Try taking the USB drive to a cell phone repair shop, or a computer shop that specializes in electronics repair, as well as data recovery specialists.  You should be able to google these in your local area.  Assuming the flash memory is not damaged, which I would doubt, the data can be recovered.  This is definitely something you would want to shop around to various places, as their prices can be wildly different.

Answer (score -1):

for whom it may concern;
 I helped someone retrieve his files. After dissection, the motherboard turned out to be broken by two, without anything noticeable on the outside.
but what turned out:
In the ixpand flash drive 3.0, there is a micro SD card hidden in the black plastic of the USB plug. I am not sure if you can get the micro SD card out without removing the metal shell. (maybe through the small holes on the side)  I had to use recovery software because the micro SD card was not readable. It turned out to be a damaged fat32 partition, and I was able to recover everything.

So the conclusion is: Do not use, the ixpand flash drive 3.0. the motherboard is way too thin, and the device too expensive. IOS on Fat32?

Regards Spookytronix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMlha.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81x61.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

My iXpand Flash Drive were plugged in my laptop and when I went to bathroom, my 120 lbs German Shepherd ran over the charging cable and knocked down my laptop landed unto the floor with the Flash Drive first. Sure enough it’s broken in 2 pieces. I tried to solder it but seems to be too small and I don’t have the equipment. So I use thumb tack push pin to wiggle around the holder, I was able to pull out the Micro SD XC chip out and was able to retrieve a very important files from there, here’s the link to the short video of how to remove the micro SD XC chip from inside the USB plug: https://youtu.be/y1QgROfoeRQ. I hope this short video helps if you ever encounter the same issues. Have a good one.

Comment: All of the information for the answer MUST be in the answer post. It should not be necessary to follow a link for the answer. You've spent all your text telling a nice story, but in order to get an answer, you need to follow the link. Please correct this by using the EDIT button.